# Socket C ansi header Post

Tags: c, socket

Olá tenho um socket em C ansi sem utilização de bibliotecas adcionais trabalhando normalmente com requisições http.
Ao requisitar em um servidor novo não obtem resposta alguma, utilizando a lib curl, resulta 100-continue e faz o processo normalmente.

Como, através do socket sem curl consigo receber os dados com um response 100-continue?

Obrigado

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você tem e exatamante em que ponto chegou. O problema está em ler dados do socket? Em interpretar a requisição http? Em enviar uma resposta válida?

Comment: Peço desculpas, quando fiz a pergunta, não havia atentado que o servidor só aceita conexões http na porta 443 com SSl, conexão que o curl faz automaticamente, por esse motivo que no curl sempre retorna e no socket não.

Estou implementando a conexão via SSL no socket em questão.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que queira acessar um servidor local, o *Apache* está ativo e se faz uma conexão através de *Socket*, após se conectar ao servidor, é necessário que seja passado um *Header*(Cabeçalho).

**main:**

```
const int PORT = 8080;
int _sock;
int res;
char buffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1"
"Host: localhost:8080"
"User-Agent: WebBrowser (<GUI>; <OS>; rv:<version>)"
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9"
"Accept-Language: pt-BR"
"Connection: keep-alive";

struct sockaddr_in serv;
struct hostent *server;

_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, TCP);
server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv.sin_port = htons(PORT);
bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
                        (char *) &serv.sin_addr.s_addr,
                        server->h_length);
int len = sizeof(serv);
res = connect(_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, len);
write(_sock,buffer, strlen(buffer))

while(1)
    if(read(_sock, &c, 1) != 1)
        break;
    else
        write(stdout, &c, 1);

close(_sock);
```

Os *WebServers* tiram as informações do usuário q acessa o servidor através desse cabeçalho. Assim não tem necessidade de usar o `curl` para fazer o requerimento ao servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Quando fiz a pergunta, não havia atentado que o servidor só aceita conexões http na porta 443 com SSl, conexão que o curl faz automaticamente, por esse motivo que no curl sempre retorna e no socket não.

Estou implementando a conexão via SSL no socket em questão.
Obrigado

Comment: @Alessandro, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta para marcar sua pergunta como respondida. Isso se a resposta resolver. E seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow (um pouco atrasado).